# Alter list of attributes listed by dir function

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

Let's assume you have an instance of the following class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

foo = Foo({'bar': 'baz'})
```

when you do `dir(foo)` you get:

```
>>> dir(foo)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_data']
```

**Note `_data` at the end of the property list**

I would like to have a way to customize what `dir` outputs for instances of my class. In this specific case, I would like to add the key-value pairs in the `_data` dictionary to be listed as additional items in the previous output, like:

```
>>> dir(foo)
['__class__', '__delattr__', ..., '_data', 'bar']
```

**Note `_data` AND `bar` at the end of the property list**

I thought there would be a *special* function to customize this in a similar way like you can customize an instance with `__str__`, `__repr__`, etc. but haven't found anything for this yet.

UPDATE: I'm looking for something that only alters the properties to display, without altering the instance `__dict__` with something like:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data
        self.__dict__.update(data)  # I would prefer not to do this
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is providing a __ dir __ method not sufficient?

Comment: It is, but I didn't know about it until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the purpose of the `__dir__` special method. See the [python documentation on `dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir).

For example:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def __dir__(self):
        return dir(object) + self.__dict__.keys() + [k for k in self._data]

foo = Foo({'bar': 'baz'})
```

Which gives this:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> dir(foo)
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '_data',
 'bar']
```

Note that it probably only really makes sense to do this if you're defining `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` as well so that the user can write something like `foo.bar`, otherwise `dir()` would be sort of misleading.